# Automatically uploading a picture file to a free online OCR resource

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to upload a .jpg file to a free online OCR site. I am using Excel VBA for this project:

```
Sub getOcrText()

 Dim ocrAddress As String: ocrAddress = "http://www.free-online-ocr.com"
 Dim picFile As String: picFile = "C:\Users\310217955\Documents\pdfdown\test.jpg"
 Dim elementCollection As Variant
 Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium
 With IE

    .Visible = True
    .Navigate (ocrAddress)
     Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Set elementCollection = IE.document.getElementsByName("fileUpload")

 End With
 IE.Quit
 Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, when I run the code to see whether I get objects to `elementCollection` I get a *Runtime error, automation error, unspecified error*, the code successfully navigates to the desired webpage.

[image]

How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change a couple lines.

First this one:

```
Dim IE As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

.

The second problem...

`IE.Busy` is not a sufficient test. Make that line the following instead:

```
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4): DoEvents: Loop
```

Comment: Hi, this solution does not overcome the error, on top of that error I'm getting the following error as well `runtime error, Automation error: object invoked has disconnected from its clients`:)

Comment: @Adhil There should be a large grey check mark next to my answer. Click it.

Comment: I dont see that option.

Comment: You found it! Thanks.